# Quadratic Bézier Curve in ipad applications

Tags: ipad, math, cgrect

I want to know about the coordinates of the Quadratic Bézier Curve.

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(context4, 10, 200);

CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context4, 150, 10, 500, 200);
```

What are the coordinates used here. Please help me? Can you please explain it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CGContextMoveToPoint(context4, 10, 200);
```

These are x,y the starting points.

```
CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context4, 150, 10, 500, 200);
```

the values are `(x1,y1)`  and `(x2,y2)` two tangents, `P1` and `P2`

Answer (score 2):

MoveToPoint sets current position. It is used later as start point P0, as denoted [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Quadratic_curves), AddQuadCurveToPoint sets control point P1 and end point P2